# Check or not objects in a Javascript API?

Tags: javascript, api, api-design

I'm writing an API in JavaScript, and I'm confused whether or not I should check if the API user is passing me the correct type on which the API expects to work. Actually not the type, but if you are passing me the object with the properties on which API will work. Is it a good practice for me to issue an error if the user does not pass an object with the properties expected for the API, or should I leave this on behalf of the JavaScript compiler?

I should check the type like this:

```
function PackageManager() {
    this.packages = {};
}

PackageManager.prototype.addPackage = function(assetPackage) {
    Array.isArray(assetPackage) ? this.addAssetPackages(assetPackage) : this.addAssetPackage(assetPackage);
}

PackageManager.prototype.addAssetPackages = function(assetPackages) {
     for(let i = 0; i < assetPackages.length; i++) 
         this.addAssetPackage(assetPackages[i]);
}

PackageManager.prototype.addAssetPackage = function(assetPackage) {
    if (!this.isAssetPackage(assetPackage))
        throw new TypeError('You are passing the argument "'+ assetPackage +'" and the addPackage function expects an AssetPackage.');
    this.packages[assetPackage.name] = {
        name: assetPackage.name,
        assets: assetPackage.assets
    };
}

PackageManager.prototype.isAssetPackage = function(val) {
    return (this.isObject(val) && val.name && val.assets ? true : false);
}

PackageManager.prototype.isObject = function(val) {
    return (typeof val === "object" && val !== null ? true : false);
}
export default PackageManager;
```

or simply let the API user handle the compiler:

```
function PackageManager() {
    this.packages = {};
}

PackageManager.prototype.addPackage = function(assetPackage) {
     Array.isArray(assetPackage) ? this.addPackages(assetPackage) : addAssetPackage(assetPackage);
}

PackageManager.prototype.addPackages = function(assetPackages) {
     for(let i = 0; i < assetPackages.length; i++)
         addAssetPackage(assetPackages[i]);
}

PackageManager.prototype.addAssetPackage = function(assetPackage) {
    this.packages[assetPackage.name] = {
        name: assetPackage.name,
        assets: assetPackage.assets
    };
}

export default PackageManager;
```

how do you handle this case in your JavaScript APIs?

Comment: What do you mean by "let the user handle the compiler?"

Comment: It's called "data validation," and yes, you should do it.

Comment: @RobertHarvey "...handle the compiler" = Let it parse the errors that the compiler gives when it passes an object that the API can not work with.

Comment: Javascript in the browser is a notoriously opaque programming language when it comes to error handling.  Sometimes you'll get an error that makes sense, sometimes you won't.  Sometimes you won't get an error at all; it will simply not work or produce the wrong result.  Do you think it's better to leave such a language to its own devices, or provide a meaningful error message so that you don't frustrate the caller?

Comment: @RobertHarvey I was told something that made me think, "JavaScript is a dynamic language, and what you are doing is wanting to use it as a typed language," and I thought a little about it and the question came to me, because maybe I should not do that type of verification, after all dynamic languages ​​give us the Duck Typed, because anyway if it passes an object that does not contain "assets", it will receive an error from the compiler soon about this, and if it does not provide a property "name" will have an "undefined" property in packages, which also probably will appear the error soon.

Comment: @RobertHarvey: Ah, but this is JavaScript. The rules are different. C#, Java and their ilk won't allow you to put a square peg into a round hole. JavaScript allows it quite easily. In some cases you make the square peg round. In other cases you make the round hole a square. This can present challenges when defining a public API. With JavaScript, there is no spoon. It's a fork... but you can use it like a spoon if you want. No one but the browser will complain.

Comment: @GregBurghardt: Yes, I am aware.  (?)

Comment: @RobertHarvey I think it might be right, because if we start checking the types, you fall into an "endless conditional hole" all over your code, then there would be the question because I'm using a dynamic language if I'm worrying so much about types like this?

Comment: If you want to type JavaScript source code, just implement TypeScript. Don't reinvent the wheel. Typing JavaScript source code is not exempt of trade-offs. It has pros and cons, like anything else in this industry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Being that JavaScript is a dynamically typed language, you can assume the users of that language know it is dynamically-typed. If you expect a certain kind of object, document it either in the how-to guides for your API, or using something like JsDoc.

The constant checking of data types at runtime is replicating what a compiler does. If you need to verify this, you need a strongly typed language. If your target platform does not support a strongly typed language, then you don't need to check data types.

1. Document what you expect
2. Add error handling where it makes business sense
3. Do not add error handling if it would normally be verified by a compiler in a strongly typed language
4. Assume your users know they are not using a strongly typed language
5. Tell them to RTFM when something wonky goes wrong

Oh, and make sure the "F" in RTFM means "Friendly" and "well-written."

There is 1 exception, however. And this exception is perfectly illustrated in your PackageManager#addPackage method. If you want to support method overloading in a language that does not support method overloading, you absolutely must check data types.

Comment: "Do not add error handling if it would normally be verified by a compiler in a strongly typed language" - this is a very good tip, I will always look at it and think now.

Comment: I don't agree with your second paragraph.  The basis for checking types yourself is not "would a strongly-typed language do it for you," because clearly a dynamically-typed language *does not.*  The basis should be *"do you need this?"*

Comment: @RobertHarvey: Since JavaScript is a dynamically typed language, the issue of "do you need [to check types]" is moot. The language doesn't support it. If you really need it, JavaScript isn't the right tool for the job. TypeScript would be an alternative, but that doesn't stop code originally written in JavaScript from calling those functions or methods that were transpiled from TypeScript to JavaScript. I feel like front end developers need to complain more about this to browser vendors and the W3C. We need a strongly typed language too.

Answer (score 0):

In this particular example code, the only **required** field to not blow up is `name`, because it gets used in

`this.packages[assetPackage.name] = ...`

The other field, `assets`, could be null (or missing) and the code would run fine.  Now, perhaps, you want to ensure that assets also exists.

#### How I would document this

1. Document that you expect objects with a required name field,
2. If desired, document that other fields, like assets and foobar, are required.

#### How I would "validate"

1. Test for the required fields, but don't bother with `typeof val === "object"` because that is, well, pretty pointless here.  You would make that test if you want to handle a String or a Number differently, as part of function overloading, but that is not the case here.
2. Just test `if (!val.name) throw...` (if you want, also test `val.assets`, etc...)  (purists note: this also prohibits **empty** names, YMMV, so you might prefer`if (val.name == null)`
3. Consider user friendly defaults for values (other than name).  For example, if assets is an object, and you don't want nulls later on, use `assets: assetPackage.assets || {}`

p.s. If your software is security related, controls a pacemaker, etc., you need more valudation!